# Oracle 11g - ORA-01565 and other errors. SPFILE

Tags: oracle

I'm pretty new to Oracle and having issues with starting XE 11g.

I was at a stage where I've created tablespaces, restored data through SQL DEV and had to increase the storage size of a  .DBF to 11Gigs to store more data.

After the DATAFILE was increased I restarted my db.

The following errors are:

> 1. ORA-01078: Failure in processing system parameters. ORA-01565: error
>      in identifying file C:....\spfilexe.ora
> 2. ORA-27046: File size is not a multiple of logical block size.
> 3. OSD-04012: file size mismatch.
> 4. O/S-Error: Os 3409 - The redirector is already installed.

Now the XE 11g webpage won't load. I've attempted investigating the SPFILEXE.ORA without luck / restarted machine / shutdown & start db.

SQLPLUS / as sysdba can't seem to load the database either. It will only load an idle instance.

I don't fancy installing everything again and restoring a 2Million record table.

Thanks.
Sam.

Comment: Can you please show us the exact steps you took to increase the storage size?

Comment: Also your ORA-27046  suggests you've edited your SPFILE, what did you put in it?

Comment: Hi Pie,
I think I accidentally added a 0 at the end of the memory_target (was 1024M* -  (10240M)) I amended this back.

Comment: The SPFILE is a _binary_ file, meaning you cannot edit it with a text editor at all. Have you backed it up?

Comment: I think the command was....

Alter Tablespace Users Resize 11g;

Comment: I didn't back it up sadly..... Is there a tool or a way I can reconfigure the SPfile?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the PFILE on the server still?

Comment: I've had a look for the Pfile on the server. Cannot seem to find it. All I can see is an empty pfile folder. Otherwise "google" tells me to create a spfile from pfile or memory... Sorry, I'm pretty new.

Comment: You could try but I don't believe it will work when your connected idle. Give it a shot.

Comment: I did the create spfile from pfile'ORA_HOME/../../init.ora' result: file created. But where!? EDIT: Found the file.. Should I replace and stop/start db?

Comment: Creating from a pfile might work when idle, but you'd have to know where the pfile is (maybe look for `initxe.ora`?); creating from memory won't because it hasn't loaded the parameters into memory from anywhere yet.

Comment: You could check in the `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` folder. If you can't find it specify a location like `create pfile='/home/oracle' from memory;`

Comment: Alright, I chuckled a little bit. I think I managed to fix this issue with the init.ora (template) file.. So I created the SPFILE from pfile with the filled out values.

Ora-01261
Ora-01263
osd-04018....

Comment: Right those above errors fixed.

Just have one more error, then hopefully my XE11g will be working as per usual...

ORA-00205 - Control files / error identifying?

Comment: If you still have your corrupt spfile, you could get the parameter values from that and use them to create a pfile; init.ora is a template so you could call it something else and then create a new spfile from that.